# Sweave - using a variable from Latex into code chunks

Tags: r, sweave

I need to use variable (ie. an argument of a custom command) from latex into a R inline code chunk. See, for instance :

```
\newcommand{\textvar}[1]{
  \textbf{
    \Sexpr{
       # Here, I would like to use the one argument of my \textvar command to do somthing in R
    }
  }
}
```

Of course, I can't just add #1 like in pure Tex, it would just comment the line in R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that because of the order in which things are run.  First `Sweave()` processes the `.Rnw` file to produce a `.tex` file, then LaTeX processes the `.tex` file to produce output.  Sweave (and hence R) knows nothing about LaTeX macro processing.

What you could do is write an R function that outputs the LaTeX you want, e.g. something like

```
textvar <- function(x) {
   paste0("\\textbf{", x, "}")
}
```

and then insert this as an inline code chunk

```
\Sexpr{textvar(x)}
```

which will expand to the LaTeX code you want your `\textvar` macro to insert.